# Create a view from both user and node content

Tags: views, 8

Is it possible in Drupal 8 to create a view from both Users and other content? I need a page that shows photo's from Users and logo's from a content type 'Organisation'.

If I make a page view from content, it will not give the possibility to select data from 'Users', and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would normally add a relationship to the view to achieve this. I'm guessing you've got a field on either the user entities the organization entities that references the other?

If you add that field as a relationship in the view that will expose that entity's fields for you to add into your view

Comment: Yes, adding that field with a relationship caused all records to show, thanks